# Is it possible to create status choice with a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have my model.py:

```
class Example(models.Model):
      STATUS_CHOICE = (
              ('status1', 'status1'),
              ('status2', 'status2'),
          )
      field= models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
      .
```

But I want to know if it's possible to have the possibility to create my STATUS_CHOICE with a model, in this manner the client can create the status as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is. It would be a ForeignKey to a `Status` model.

```
class Status(models.Model):
      slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
      title = models.TextField()


class Example(models.Model):
      status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

- You may want to have a migration create initial statuses, unless all of them should be user-defined.
- You will probably want to use a `SlugRelatedField` (or whatsitcalled) in DRF, so users can just post `{"status": "foo"}`, not `{"status": 1}` or whatever happens to be the foo status's primary key.

Comment: could you explain me better with an example?

Comment: Added an example.